# Correlation functions under rescaling

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, renormalization, effective-field-theory

I was reading [this](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/dbs26/AQFT/Wilsonchap.pdf) lecture note on Wilson's renormalization group and have hit a snag. I can't obtain equation 5.22. I tried to do the following:

\begin{equation}
\Gamma^{(n)}_{s\Lambda}(sx_1,…,sx_n;g_i(s\Lambda)):=\frac{1}{\mathcal{Z}}\int_{{C^\infty}(M)_{≤s\Lambda}}\mathcal{D}\phi\exp(-S^{\text{eff}}_{s\Lambda}[\sqrt{Z_{s\Lambda}}\phi;g(s\Lambda)])\phi(sx_1)…\phi(sx_n)=(s^{2-d})^{n/2}\frac{1}{\mathcal{Z}}\int_{{C^\infty}(M)_{≤s\Lambda}}\mathcal{D}\phi\exp(-S^{\text{eff}}_{s\Lambda}[\sqrt{Z_{s\Lambda}}\phi;g(s\Lambda)])\phi(x_1)…\phi(x_n)=(s^{2-d})^{n/2}\Gamma^{(n)}_{s\Lambda}(x_1,…,x_n;g_i(s\Lambda))
\end{equation}
where the last equality follows from how $\phi$ behaves under rescaling. $\Gamma$ is the n-point correlation function. This would imply,
\begin{equation}
\Gamma^{(n)}_{\Lambda}(x_1,…,x_n;g_i(\Lambda))=[s^{d-2}\frac{Z_{\Lambda}}{Z_{s\Lambda}}]^{n/2}\Gamma^{(n)}_{s\Lambda}(sx_1,…,sx_n;g_i(s\Lambda))
\end{equation}
However, in the lecture notes,
\begin{equation}
\Gamma^{(n)}_{\Lambda}(x_1,…,x_n;g_i(\Lambda))=[s^{2-d}\frac{Z_{\Lambda}}{Z_{s\Lambda}}]^{n/2}\Gamma^{(n)}_{\Lambda}(sx_1,…,sx_n;g_i(s\Lambda))
\end{equation}
The justification they give for this is that the action is invariant under $x\rightarrow sx$ AND $\Lambda\rightarrow\Lambda/s$. Since this is just a simple rescaling, the coupling constants need to be evaluated at $s\Lambda$ instead of $\Lambda$. I really don't understand why this is needed. The action is invariant anyway, so why do we even need to bother about it? Is this just a misprint or does this relation actually hold?

Comment: I think its important to note that the first line of equation 5.22 is just a statement of invariance of correlation functions after integration down to the lower momentum scale.  AFTER this integration has been performed, we have couplings at the lower scale. Now, we put our thinking hat on and realize that there is a symmetry of the action that went unnoticed, the rescaling. We perform this rescaling AFTER integrating down to the lower scale, to push the cut off to its original value(numerically). This is why its important to continue evaluating the couplings at the lower scale.

Comment: @Anonjohn but why aren't the couplings changing due to the rescaling? They are also a function of the cutoff so if you rescale it (which you need to do in order to keep the action invariant) shouldn't they also vary?

Comment: These are two separate operations. Couplings change when you integrate down. Thats how they depend on scale. When you rescale, you haven't changed the theory morally. You have changed the "scale". What you previously called 2cm, you will call 1cm. What you previously called 2Mev, you will call 4Mev. This overall change in scale is merely nomenclature. The couplings, being dimensionless, are unaffected by your change in language. In fact, if you also changed the couplings, you will not have symmetry of the action: check this explicitly, if you like.

Comment: Concretely, my suggestion to clarify this point is: take equation 5.1, perform rescaling, and check that for a symmetry of the action under scaling, the couplings need to be left alone.

Comment: Alright, assuming that the coupling constants won't change under the rescaling how do you explain the $s^{(2-d)}$ ? I am consistently getting it to be $s^{(d-2)}$.

Comment: $ d^d (sx) (\partial \phi (sx))^2= d^d x (\partial \phi (x))^2 $. This means, $s^{(d-2)/2} \phi(sx)=\phi(x)$. 5.21 follows from rearrangement.

Comment: Yes that is correct, I used that in deriving the first equation. Therefore, $\Gamma(x)=s^{(d-2)n/2}\Gamma(sx)$. After substituting it in eq. 5.19 I'm getting the wrong answer.

Comment: I think your problem is notational. Here are a relevant set of equations that will help you follow the reasoning with "nice" notation. $s^{(d-2)/2}\phi'(x')=\phi (x)$, $\langle \phi(x_1) \phi(x_2) \rangle = \Gamma (x_1,x_2,g,\Lambda)$. Now a symmetry means that: $\langle \phi'(x'_1) \phi'(x'_2) \rangle = \Gamma (x'_1,x'_2,g,\Lambda')$. Follow these equations to get the tong answer.